# Cannot see all library items

Tags: 2010, document-library

In a document library I can see 429 items and my colleague can see 431.

- None of the documents are checked out
- We have the same permissions (Full Control to site and Full Control to the library, I also have a fewer powers higher up in the site collection)
- We are using the same Document view
- We have tried opening the Document Library in Explorer and the total items is the same as above
- The 2 documents I cannot see were uploaded by my colleague, she is not aware of how to set up item level permissions but perhaps she did by mistake..?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What are the item level permissions in the library settings? Are there any files showing up for you if you go to the Manage files which have no checked in version link in the library settings?

Comment: Ah ha! I think you may have solved this! There are 7 items  in there, including the 2 my colleague can see that I can't which are checked out to her

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to look at:

- The item level permissions on the library - This can hide files from admins if it is set to only be visible to the creator.
- Manage files which have no checked in version - This can hide files from the admins if you have required metadata that is not supplied. The file remains checked out to the uploader as a draft until the metadata is supplied and checked in.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your colleague has used the Windows Explorer to upload the document. Using this way for uploads prevents the check in.

Only she and site collection administrators can see the document until she checks it in using the UI.